# Is there a way of changing the key of a hash via sort / sort_by?

Tags: ruby

Currently working through a question thats trying to get me to transform the former into the later

```
{ a: 2, b: 5, c: 1 } => { a: 1, b: 2, c: 5 }
```

tried to do this with

```
hash = { a: 2, b: 5, c: 1 }.sort_by {|k,v| v}.to_h
```

this gives this => `{:c=>1, :a=>2, :b=>5}`

how do I change the key of the hash whilst sorting the values?

Comment: @lurker Ruby hashes are ordered these days, they maintain insertion order just like JavaScript objects (in recent versions of JavaScript of course).

Comment: @muistooshort ok thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to split the hash into keys and values, sort each of those separately, and then put them back together as a hash.

In that case, you could do something like this:

```
hash.to_a.transpose.map(&:sort).transpose.to_h
```

Step by step it works like this:

```
# First array-ify the hash into key/value pairs
hash.to_a
# [[:a, 2], [:b, 5], [:c, 1]] 

# Then transpose to group the keys and values together
hash.to_a.transpose
# [[:a, :b, :c], [2, 5, 1]]

# Then sort the keys and values separately
hash.to_a.transpose.map(&:sort)
# [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 5]] 

# And transpose again to get key/value pairs
hash.to_a.transpose.map(&:sort).transpose
# [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 5]] 

# And combine the array of key/value pairs into a hash
hash.to_a.transpose.map(&:sort).transpose.to_h
# {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>5}
```

You could also manually do the `hash.to_a.transpose` step like this:

```
[hash.keys, hash.values].map(&:sort).transpose.to_h
```

You don't even have to assume that `#keys` and `#values` will produce arrays in any particular order since you're sorting everything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What's about the following approach?

```
{ a: 2, b: 5, c: 1 }.then { |hash| [hash.keys.sort, hash.values.sort].transpose }.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = { a: 2, b: 5, c: 1 }
```

```
a = h.values.sort
  #=> [1, 2, 5] 
h.transform_values { a.shift }
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>5}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.keys.zip(h.values.sort).to_h
#  {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>5}
```

This just sorts the values, not the keys. Since your original example had pre-sorted keys, it wasn't clear from the question whether you expected those to be sorted as well if they weren't already

If you want to sort the keys and the values and have them linked to each other, then you can `sort` the keys as well:

```
hash.keys.sort.zip(h.values.sort).to_h
# {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>5}
```